# inserting <--!pagebreak--> every 200 characters automatically

Tags: nextpage, split

:)

I'm trying to split a post in pages at every 200 characters with `<!--nextpage-->`

I found this code [on this page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110225/divide-post-content-into-separate-divs-for-every-500-characters-or-any-other-ch) that actually looks pretty good (for my understanding alone - yes I'm a newbie to development):

```
<?php
$content = get_the_content();
$strings = wordwrap($content, 500, "<!--break-->"); //insert this every 500 chars, but preserve whole words.
$chunks = explode("<!--break-->", $strings); create a new string of 500-char sections.

ob_start(); // buffer the output of the following expressions...
foreach($chunks as $chunk_content) {
    echo '<span>'; // use <span> instead of <div> so as to not interrupt the paragraph formatting of the content when viewed normally (graceful degradation).
    echo $chunk_content;
    echo '</span> ';
    }
$segmented_content = ob_get_contents(); // put the results of the above expressions into a variable.
ob_end_clean(); // discard the expressions that were buffered.
echo nl2br($segmented_content); // put the result through a filter which replaces line-breaks with <br> tags.
?>
```

I tried to replace `<!--break-->` by `<!--nextpage-->`, it looks like `<!--nextpage-->` is not recognized as such in html!

How can it work?

(Yes i've tried a lot of code functions and plugins... I've already inserted `wp_link_pages();` still none would work :/ )

Thanks for any help...

Comment: What if after 200 chars you are positioned within an `<img alt="">` tag? Splitting that img tag, could bring down the site's layout.

Comment: You could try to grab the closing `</p>` tags, but then we should also watch out for nested tags. Maybe a clever usage of `DomDocument` could help us determine where we are positioned in the DOM tree? This might of course get easier if this would be pure text (no HTML). Don't know if [my answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/194155/26350) would be of any help?